# Why are my file names being cut off in the Open Project dialog (NetBeans)

Tags: java, netbeans

I don't know why this is happening, but after I installed an outside look and feel plugin for netbeans 7.4, when I try and open a project, all the file names are cut off. So I changed it back to a system look and feel and still getting the same result. Maybe It has nothing to do with the plugin. I have no clue.

[image]

If you've ran into this problem and have a possible fix, can you please explain the steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=226761), if it is your case. It also contains steps to workaround it:

open Tools | Plugins -> Installed -> check 'Show details'  -> select 'Dark Nimbus Theme' -> Uninstall